# How to reorder CSV columns using apache NIFI processor?

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-nifi

In my scenario,Users have the option to upload a CSV file and can map the columns of that CSV file to a predefined schema.I need to reorder the columns of that CSV file based on user mapping and upload it to HDFS. Is there any way to achieve this via a NIFI processor ?

Comment: Sure, you can write your own processor to do whatever

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with a `ConvertRecord` processor. Register an Avro schema describing the expected format in a Schema Registry (controller service), and create a `CSVReader` implementation to convert this incoming data to the generic Apache NiFi internal record format. Similarly, use a `CSVRecordSetWriter` with your output schema to write the data back to CSV in whatever columnar order you like.

For more information on the record processing philosophy and some examples, see [Record-oriented data with NiFi](https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/record-oriented-data-with-nifi) and [Apache NiFi Records and Schema Registries](https://bryanbende.com/development/2017/06/20/apache-nifi-records-and-schema-registries).